# php - Cannot redeclare autoloading function even though it is already declared

Tags: php

I have a web app that has some files. The files that I am currently concerned about is the `index.php` and the `inc/Autoloader.php`.

Currently, in the index.php, I have a `include(dirname(__FILE__)."/inc/Autoloader.php");` in my `index.php`. Before that line, I have included my header, which has my navbar and others.

When I attempt to access my index, PHP outputs this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare load_class() (previously declared in /redacted/directory/webroot/inc/Autoloader.php:17) in /redacted/directory/webroot/inc/Autoloader.php on line 17
```

This is my autoloader function:

```
function Infinia_load_class($classname) {

    // Don't __DIR__ (PHP Magic Constant __DIR__ is not in PHP 5.3)

    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'infinia_class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';

    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/../InfiniaLegit.config.php")) {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/../InfiniaLegit.config.php";
        } else {
            require dirname(__FILE__)."/config.php";
        }
    }


}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('Infinia_load_class', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('Infinia_load_class');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        Infinia_load_class($classname);
    }
}
```

I have checked through the project and I do not see any signs of redeclaring the function.

[Project Git Repository](https://github.com/InfiniaPress/InfiniaHome)

If anyone knows what is happening, help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit 1: Update to latest Autoloader in Git**

Comment: 1. The above code differs from the autoloader in the git repo. 2. Why are you requiring the same config file every time you autoload a class? 3. With the above code, it looks like you could get many "already declared" since some config files are classes that will be loaded over and over again. Let the autoloader just load classes, if they aren't loaded yet.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the only reason i am loading the config in the autoloader because the config has to be loaded in **every** file

Comment: Then you need to rethink your design. Make a config class that loads the configuration file and reuse the same class instance. Either way, you will get errors if you keep requiring the same class over and over.